# create a class with a method on it in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I have been working on this for days, and so far no luck. Every time I run this code I am being told that it was expected to be true (or false) depending on how I do the function.

```
function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail){
  // Exercise Two: Now that you have created your own class, 
  // you will create a class with a method on it.
  // In this class create 4 properties: username, password, email, and checkPassword.
  // Set the value of username to name,
  // Set the value of password to pw,
  // Set the value of email to mail
  // Set the value of checkPassword to a function. 
  // The checkPassword function takes a string as it's only argument.
  // Using the 'this' keyword check to see if the password on the class is the same as 
  // the string being passed in as the parameter. Return true or false.

  this.username = name,
  this.password = pw,
  this.email = mail
  this.checkPassword = function checkPassword() {
    return this.password 
  }

  }
```

Comment: What have you tried, you only show the "class" where do you call it? What are you passing in for pw?

Comment: "Every time I run this code I am being told that it was expected to be true (or false) depending on how I do the function." can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the `tested_pw` argument to the `checkPassword` function

```
function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail){
  // Exercise Two: Now that you have created your own class, 
  // you will create a class with a method on it.
  // In this class create 4 properties: username, password, email, and checkPassword.
  // Set the value of username to name,
  // Set the value of password to pw,
  // Set the value of email to mail
  // Set the value of checkPassword to a function. 
  // The checkPassword function takes a string as it's only argument.
  // Using the 'this' keyword check to see if the password on the class is the same as 
  // the string being passed in as the parameter. Return true or false.

  this.username = name,
  this.password = pw,
  this.email = mail
  this.checkPassword = function checkPassword(tested_pw) {
    return this.password === tested_pw
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I am a beginner with javascript but this worked for me.

```
function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail){
  // Exercise Two: Now that you have created your own class, 
  // you will create a class with a method on it.
  // In this class create 4 properties: username, password, email, and checkPassword.
  // Set the value of username to name,
  // Set the value of password to pw,
  // Set the value of email to mail
  // Set the value of checkPassword to a function. 
  // The checkPassword function takes a string as it's only argument.
  // Using the 'this' keyword check to see if the password on the class is the same as 
  // the string being passed in as the parameter. Return true or false.

  this.username = name;
  this.password = pw;
  this.email = mail;
  this.checkPassword = function(pw){
    return this.password === pw;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slow down and look at it; piece it together:

```
this.username = name;
this.password = pw;
this.email = mail;
this.checkPassword = function(str) {    
  if (this.password === str) {    
    return true;    
  }
  else (this.checkPassword !== this.password); {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to read the instruction very carefully.

```
function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail){
  // Exercise Two: Now that you have created your own class, 
  // you will create a class with a method on it.
  // In this class create 4 properties: username, password, email, and checkPassword.
  // Set the value of username to name,
  // Set the value of password to pw,
  // Set the value of email to mail
  // Set the value of checkPassword to a function. 
  // The checkPassword function takes a string as it's only argument.
  // Using the 'this' keyword check to see if the password on the class is the same as 
  // the string being passed in as the parameter. Return true or false.

  this.username = name;
  this.password = pw;
  this.email = mail;
  this.checkPassword = function(testPass){
    return this.password === testPass;
  };
}
```